# Extracting specific elements/values from html

Tags: vba

I am trying to do either a) or b) below. I would prefer a), if I can figure it out.
Refer to the html at the end.

a) extract the values of the following items--the items in "" are static, but the associated values will change. I want to extract just the value.

```
"locality" = Paris
"region" = Paris
"country-name" = France
"latitude" = 48.85534
"longitude" = 2.35048
```

b) simply extract the entire element `<div class="vcard">...<div>`

I am trying to reuse code from someone else, and make it do what I want. But I am having trouble wrapping my head around the code. I manage to extract some values. But it is messy. I think the code can be made much much better:

## THE VBA

```
Sheet1.WebBrowser1.Navigate (Sheet1.Range("C1"))

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until Sheet1.WebBrowser1.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

the_html_code = Sheet1.WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHTML

    the_output_row = 2
    start_of_item = InStr(the_html_code, "locality")
    the_value = Mid(the_html_code, start_of_item + 39, Len(the_html_code))
    the_html_code = Mid(the_html_code, start_of_item + 8, Len(the_html_code))
    the_value = Mid(the_value, 1, InStr(the_value, Chr(62)) - 1)
        Sheet1.Range("L" & the_output_row) = the_value
```

## THE HTML

```
    <script>
        if (typeof (aadSponsoredLinksObj) != 'undefined' && aadSponsoredLinksObj.type == 'google' && aadSponsoredLinksObj.show_links == true) {
            document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
        } else if (typeof (aadSponsoredLinksObj) == 'undefined') {
            jQuery('#ad-links').remove();
        }
    </script>
<div id="tracking-pixels"></div>

</div>
<!-- /#wrap -->

    <div class="vcard">
        <span class="adr">
            <span class="locality">
                <span class="value-title" title="Paris" ></span>
            </span>
            <abbr class="region" title="Paris">
                <span class="value-title" title="75" ></span>
            </abbr>
            <abbr class="country-name" title="France">
                <span class="value-title" title="FR" ></span>
            </abbr>
        </span>
        <span class="geo">
            <span class="latitude">
                <span class="value-title" title="48.85534" ></span>
            </span>
            <span class="longitude">
                <span class="value-title" title="2.35048"></span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _qoptions = { qacct: 'p-4b4gl_1fWISuU' };
        if (typeof (apgPageInfoObj) != 'undefined' && apgPageInfoObj.crumb_trail) {
            _qoptions.labels = apgPageInfoObj.crumb_trail.join('.');
```

Comment: Why don't you use a proper `DOM` parser? It will be about 1000% more efficient than trying to use string functions to parse HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As David Zemens suggested, you could use the DOM parser in MSXML.  You can add a reference to Microsoft XML (might as well go with the latest, v6.0) in the VBA References dialog.  There is an online reference to this library [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms766487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).